# Check if all checkboxes of form are checked

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple checkboxes that I created dinamically from code, So I know I can get checkboxes using:

```
foreach (var checkBox in this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())
            {

            }
```

But that I want to know or my desire result is to know if all checkboxes of my form are checked something like a bool returning true if all checkboxes are checked or false if one is missing... How can I achieve that? Regards

```
bool allChecked = ...
```

Comment: Can't you just get all the unchecked controls by reversing the logic of your where clause and checking that the count is equal to zero?

Comment: Are any of the CheckBoxes inside panels or other containers?

Comment: Using your code above, you could start out with `bool allChecked = true;` and inside your `foreach` add the lines: `if (!checkbox.Checked) { allChecked = false; break; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify that all checkboxes on the form are checked, even those that belong to other container controls, you will have to iterate over each control's `Controls` collection (not just those belonging to the `Form`).

One way to do this is to write a recursive method that takes in a container control (like the `Form`) and examines all the controls in it's collection. If any contained control is a `Checkbox` and it isn't checked, then return `false`. Otherwise, perform a recursive check on that control's `Controls` collection. If neither of these checks is false, then return true.

For example:

```
private static bool ContainedCheckboxesAreChecked(Control containerControl)
{        
    // For each control in the container
    foreach (Control control in containerControl.Controls)
    {
        // Return false if the control is a checkbox and it's not checked
        if (!(control as CheckBox)?.Checked ?? false) return false;

        // Do a recursive check on this control's Controls collection
        if (!ContainedCheckboxesAreChecked(control)) return false;
    }

    // If we got this far, return true
    return true;
}
```

Now, if you call this and pass in the main form as the container control, you will examine all controls on the form, including in all containers (even nested containers):

```
bool allCheckBoxesAreChecked = ContainedCheckboxesAreChecked(this);
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply as

```
bool allChecked = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(c => c.Checked);
```

I am not sure what `AllControls` (in original unedited post) is. Because this property doesn't seem to be a standard one. This example uses the standard Controls collection present in any control container like the top level Form

The problem is more complex if you have your CheckBoxes distributed inside different control containers. In that case you could use a recursive function that iteratively explore your controls and count how many of them are checked

```
int result = RecursiveCheck(f.Controls);
if(result > 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Something is not checked");

int RecursiveCheck(Control.ControlCollection col)
{
    int count = 0;
    foreach(Control c in col)
    {
        if (c.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            count += c.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Count(x => !x.Checked);
            count += RecursiveCheck(c.Controls);
        }   
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: I try it but it always return True value

Comment: Did you have your checkboxes inside some kind of container? (A panel or a groupbox) In this case you need to use the controls collection of the container

Comment: Yes, they are inside a FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: Then change _this_ with the name of your FlowLayoutPanel

Comment: Problem is they are inside FlowLayoutPanel, but inside it I have GroupBoxes, so each GroupBox have different  checkboxes, I have list of groupBox so I iterate as:  `foreach (var g in groupBoxes)
            { }`, but now, how can I know if all checkboxes are checked if they are in different Groupboxes?

Comment: That's requires a recursive function.

Answer (score 0):

if you are sure that Checkboxes available, you can use

```
 var allChecked = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().All(x => x.Checked);
```

but if there is possibility that the `Enumerable` yields no result then you need to use the code below. because All operator returns `true` for empty `Enumerable`

```
    bool allChecked = false;
    var checkBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
    if (checkBoxes.Any())
        allChecked = checkboxes.All(x => x.Checked);
```

Comment: I try but it always returning True value

Comment: It returns true but this may be undesirable since no checkboxes is found in your this.Controls