# How to retrieve a list of checkboxes selected among all those of the form?

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, subset, checked

I have about 20 checkbox's on the GUI I'm working on and depending on which ones are checked, determines the inputs I need.

I know how to check if a checkbox is checked or not, and can determine the inputs that way.

But I don't want to do that for all 20+ checkbox's.

Is there a way to get the checked checkboxes?

Something like:

```
string[] ports = new string[3];
ports[] = list_of_checkboxs_that_are_checked;
```

And then just limit the user to only selecting 3, or however many?

Comment: _forms_ tag means _WinForms_?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I removed that one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if all checkboxes of form are checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030437/check-if-all-checkboxes-of-form-are-checked) this is just one example, many more on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over them and iterate on the controls on the form.

```
   foreach(Control c in this.Controls)
   {
      if(c is CheckBox)
      {
         // Do stuff here/logic
      }
   }
```

Or do a more LINQ/Lamba-ish type approach of

```
var checkList = YourForm.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked).ToList();


checkList.ForEach(x => {
    //Do stuff  here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Suppose that you have all your checkboxes in the same container (form, panel, groupbox?) then you can simply use a Linq expression to retrieve all the checked ones and limit the retrieval to only the first three-

```
var checks = YourForm.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>().Where(x => x.Checked).Take(3);
foreach(CheckBox chk in checks)
{
    .....
}
```

Of course if your  checkboxes are inside another kind of container you should check the *YourForm* forms's placeholder with the name of your container.